# Style MediaElement in Windows Universal

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, uwp

I am working on a windows universal app called ProPlayer and you may see this preview app on Windows Store .
Now I am working on a new version and I used MediaElement instead of Microsoft player framework in this new version . I am trying to modify some parts of MediaElement but couldn't find any way . I used AreMediaTransportControlsEnabled to show this controls and generate a resource dictionary for media element style . I want to make background of MediaTransportControls transparent or change the opacity of these controls  .
[image: Shot]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8216043684/Untitled.png))</sub>

How does it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible for the system default media transport controls.

You need to create your control or just simply put something like a stackpanel and put it into a popup control to replace the default system media transport controls, cause the system default one doesn't expose required property you want.

There is [a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx) and [the relevant sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be) for win8.1. I didn't try everything in UWP, but the principle is same, so you can start from there. And you can add more cool design on the panel to make your ProPlayer more PRO. :)

Comment: Thanks I used a ResourceDictionary to create my own MediaTransportControls and now it's transparent :) thanks for your help , that's cool .